# Use data in foreign key model prior to saving in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm prototyping an estimating application.

Each Estimate model will have one or more Part models.

Here is the beginning of my models:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    estimate = models.ForeignKey('Estimate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Estimate(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    stitch = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    stitch_speed = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    stitch_rate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    boxes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    freight = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    overall_markup = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

I have the Estimate model appearing in the admin with Part models in a StackedInline.

```
class PartInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Part
    extra = 1


class EstimateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Estimate
    inlines = [PartInline]
    list_display = ['number', 'description', 'customer', 'price']
```

Ideally, I would go into the admin, create a new Estimate, fill out its Parts, and then click Save.

Ultimately, my Estimate model will need to use data from the Part model to perform calculations before saving to the database. For example, each Part will contain its own price. The price from each Part will need to be added to the total Estimate price.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to send data from the Part model to the Estimate model prior to saving.

Any suggestions? Is there a standard way of passing data between models before saving?

Comment: Are you sure you need to save the price in the estimate? It's easy to calculate this when you need to display it (by annotating the sum of the related part prices).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hmm....I hadn't really thought about only displaying the total price, but that may work. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to export a PDF with all the data, so I assumed I would need to store a total price, but maybe that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you could use a **[pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)** signal where you can get all parts assoicated to your `Estimate` instance. Something like:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from somewhere import Estimate

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Estimate)
def pre_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # instance is your Estimate object that you currently save
    # you can get all part objects with:
    parts = instance.part_set.all() # a QuerySet list with your parts
    for part in parts:
        # do something with each part
```

**EDIT**: In order to get all parts using the `_set` function you have to reverse the logic so `Part` instances save before `Estimate` by overriding `EstimateAdmin`'s `save_formset` function:

```
class EstimateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        formset.save() # this saves your parts
        form.instance.save() # this saves the Estimate
```

Comment: Does this assume that the parts are already saved in the database though? They would be entered in the admin when the estimate is created.

Comment: Nope, the parent e.x `Estimate` is created first, then `Part` objects.

Comment: Did you add this to a `signals.py` files? What else should it require to work?

Comment: Nevermind. I put it in the models.py file itself. I know that's recommended against, but I couldn't get it to work any other way.

Comment: Ah. This doesn't work upon initial save of the Estimate and Part. I'm assuming it's because the parts aren't already in the database, so `parts = instance.part_set.all()` doesn't pull anything because nothing's there at the time of pre-save.

Comment: You can reverse that logic to save parts before the estimate. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!